# Generating fields in 2nd page only in Crystal report using VS2010

Tags: sql, visual-studio-2010, crystal-reports

Hi i have a simple question about crystal report. I created three pages in Crystal report, in codes i have generated fields in the first page, second page (using Details section a) i want to generate fields but the problem is it adds pages not the fields..

### **Pages details:**

**page 1:** i all about cash on hand and its details

**page 2:** cash break down

**page 3:** all about the user logged in

### **Problem:**

When i run the project, reports generate pages which is suppose to be just 3 pages, on first page there is no problem but in second page i only have one row of cash breakdown, third page has no problem also, fourth page it repeats first page, fifth page i only have one row of cash breakdown and suppose to be at the second page (second row)..

**Question:** How can i generate that number of rows in the second page? Is it possible?

[Page 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xkFZ3.png)

[Page 5 that should be at page 2 next to the first row](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z39ud.png)

**Codes:**

```
        Dim dtt As New DataTable
        With dtt
            .Columns.Add("col")
            .Columns.Add("col1")
            .Columns.Add("col3")
            .Columns.Add("col4")
            .Columns.Add("col5")
            .Columns.Add("col6")
            .Columns.Add("col7")
            .Columns.Add("col8")
            .Columns.Add("col9")
            .Columns.Add("col10")
            .Columns.Add("col11")
            .Columns.Add("col12")
            .Columns.Add("col13")
            .Columns.Add("col14")
            .Columns.Add("col15")
            .Columns.Add("col16")
            .Columns.Add("col17")
            .Columns.Add("col18")
            .Columns.Add("col86")
            .Columns.Add("col19")
            .Columns.Add("col20")
            .Columns.Add("col21")
            .Columns.Add("col22")
            .Columns.Add("col23")
            .Columns.Add("col36") /**page 2 starts here (cash denominations ---> such as 1000.00, 500.00, 200.00, 100.00 and so on) **/
            .Columns.Add("col37") /** (number of cash denomination) **/
            .Columns.Add("col38") /** (total cash) **/
            .Columns.Add("col39")
            .Columns.Add("col40")
            .Columns.Add("col41")
        End With
        For Each drr As DataGridViewRow In Me.table1.Rows
            dtt.Rows.Add( _
            drr.Cells("Column1").Value, _
            drr.Cells("Column2").Value, _
            drr.Cells("Column3").Value, _
            drr.Cells("Column4").Value, _
            drr.Cells("Column5").Value, _
            drr.Cells("Column6").Value, _
            drr.Cells("Column7").Value, _
            drr.Cells("Column8").Value, _
            drr.Cells("Column9").Value, _
            drr.Cells("Column10").Value, _
            drr.Cells("Column11").Value, _
            drr.Cells("Column12").Value, _
            drr.Cells("Column13").Value, _
            drr.Cells("Column14").Value, _
            drr.Cells("Column15").Value, _
            drr.Cells("Column16").Value, _
            drr.Cells("Column17").Value, _
            drr.Cells("Column18").Value, _
            drr.Cells("Column19").Value, _
            drr.Cells("Column20").Value, _
            drr.Cells("Column21").Value, _
            drr.Cells("Column22").Value, _
            drr.Cells("Column23").Value, _
            drr.Cells("Column24").Value, _
            drr.Cells("Column25").Value, _
            drr.Cells("Column26").Value, _
            drr.Cells("Column27").Value, _
            drr.Cells("Column28").Value, _
            drr.Cells("Column29").Value, _
            drr.Cells("Column30").Value _
                )
        Next
```

Thanks in advance, hope somebody understand my problem..

Comment: how are you braking data between pages? what is the logic?

Comment: on crystal report i just added sections in details.. i don't know how to brake pages..

Comment: can you show design aswell?

Comment: yea i included two pictures. i can include only two

Comment: [this is the design]
(http://i.stack.imgur.com/QKrCB.png)

Comment: details repeats for every row so only one row is displayed in one iteration... it you need all cash break down on only single page then sub report is the best option so that all cash will be printed first and then rest will be printed... let me know if you need further clarification

Comment: ahhh yea maybe that is the best solution but the problem is i don't know how to create a sub-report in crystal report.. can you teach me how? i will search it also on how..

Comment: There will be a option `insert sub report`.. click that and a window apperas there you can see two options `create new or chose existing one`.....in that select you created report when you click ok a link will be attached to mouse place that link in detail section and if you wish you can link main rpeort and sub report else just leave it as it is  and now in sub report place only cash break down and delete remaining fileds and sections and refresh the report.. you can see the data in preview